# Testing nested React components

Tags: javascript, jasmine, reactjs, jestjs

I'm writing tests for my react application. But when I try to render a nested component, then I got the error `TitleBar is not defined` and the test fails.

```
jest.dontMock('FUW.js');
jest.dontMock('TitleBar.js');

var React = require('react/addons');
var TitleBar = require('../js/components/TitleBar.js');
var FirstUseWindow = require('../js/components/windows/FirstUseWindow.js');
var TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;


describe('First use wizard', function(){
    afterEach(function(done){//cleanup the DOM
        React.unmountComponentAtNode(document.body);
        setTimeout(done);
    });

    var FirstUseWindowElement = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
        <div>
        <FirstUseWindow />
        </div>
    );
});
```

The FirstUseWindow contains a TitleBar element which causes the error.

**FUW.js**

```
if (React === undefined) {
    var React = require('react/addons');
}

var FirstUseWindow = React.createClass({
    firstUseComplete:function(){
    },    
    render:function(){
        return(
            <div>
                <TitleBar text="tested" />

            </div>
        );
    }
});

if (module !== undefined) {
    module.exports = FirstUseWindow;
}
```

**TitleBar.js**

```
if (React === undefined) {
    var React = require('react/addons');
}

var TitleBar = React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        return(
            <header className="bar bar-nav">
                <h1 className="title">{this.props.text}</h1>
            </header>
        );
    }
});

if (module != undefined) {
    module.exports = TitleBar;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Title bar is undefined because its not being required in fuw.js